# Proving the Existence of a Monochromatic Rectangle in an 8x8 2-Coloring Array

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given an 8x8 array of dots colored either red or blue, prove their must exist a monochromatic rectangle regardless of how the 64 dots are colored. A monochromatic rectangle is defined as a rectangle whose four corners are dots of the array and are all of the same color.

I know this has something to do with the Pigeonhole Principle, but I don't know how to apply it. I also know that in a 3x9 array, there must be at least one monochromatic rectangle. Consider this 3x9 array (with 3 rows and 9 columns). Then in each column of 3 dots, given the 2-coloring arrangement, at least two dots must be the same color by the Pigeonhole Principle.

Secondly, there are $2^3 = 8$ ways a column of 3 dots can be colored. Therefore, with 9 columns, again by the Pigeonhole Principle, at least two of these columns must be colored with the exact same pattern. However, this is only half of the desired monochromatic rectangle, mainly the vertical sides. But because in any vertical array of 3 dots, two of the dots must be colored the same, the horizontal sides of the rectangle are created by connecting these pairs of dots. This completes the monochromatic rectangle.

However, proving the existance of a monochromatic rectangle in this specific 3x9 case is still pretty far off from the desired 8x8 proof. Are there any suggestions on how I can apply a similar logic when approaching a proof for this case?

I appreciate any and all help.

-A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if the following argument works:

We can assume that the first four dots of the first row are of the same colour, say red. If there is any other row in whose first $4$ dots there are at least $2$ of them are red, then we are done. Otherwise, there are only $5$ possible configurations for the first $4$ dots of the rows, namely $4$ for $1$ red, $3$ blue, $1$ for $0$ red, $4$ blue. Since there are $7$ rows other than the first row, there are two rows which have the same configuration for their first $4$ dots, hence we can derive a monochromatic rectangle from these two rows.

Comment: This argument actually shows that the statement holds for "$7\times 8$".

Comment: How come you started off with the first four dots of the first row? Why not the first $n$ dots for $1\leq n \leq 8$? Why specifically 4?

Comment: At least half of the $8$ dots are of the same colour, and obviously permuting the columns doesn't make trouble.

Comment: Right, I didn't see that. Thanks. Also, instead of counting each case separately, is there a formula you can use to solve for both? For example, you said "4 for this case and 1 for this case" for a total of 5 cases. Is there a more succinct way to compute the 5 total cases? Perhaps with something like stars and bars or simple computation of combinations? My knowledge of counting is really weak, so this subject is something I struggle with in particular.

Comment: Why does this show the case is solved for the 7x8 and not the 8x8? If you have select the first row, and one row from the remaining seven, doesn't that cover all 8?

Comment: As we need only $6$ more rows other than the first row, we prove a stronger result, namely for $7\times 8$, then the case $8\times 8$ follows trivially.

Comment: Thank you. One last question, sorry. How is the 7x8 stronger than the first? Is it because it can be applied to more cases than simply an 8x8 one can? I don't really understand the definition of 'stronger'.

Comment: If there is a monochromatic rectangle in the stronger case, there is also that in the weaker case.

Comment: Ok, you stated " Since there are 7 rows other than the first row..." Since you've now explained you can find the stronger case, then could the sentence be rewritten as "Since there are 6 other rows" since you only need 7 rows, not 8, for the stronger case?

Comment: Exactly what I mean!

Comment: Thank you for bearing with my lack of counting knowledge. You've helped me tremendously :)

Comment: @Salomo Can you adapt your answer to this similar question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4466570/question-about-alignment-of-objects I do not understand some of the constants chosen by you in your answer so I cannot directly transpose your argument..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple proof by contradiction; it's guaranteed even just in one column.

There are 64 squares in your array and eight in one column. For each one in a column to be polychromatic, you need at least one vertex to be different to the others.

There are two ways for the squares to be monochromatic and $2^4$ ways to make squares with no restriction (two choices at each vertex), so 14 possible squares. Another way to see this is that we have repeated sequences of four items; each sequence will be polychromatic if we pick *exactly* one, two, or three of the elements to be of one color and leave the remainder to another color; this is $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{j} = \binom{4}{1} + \binom{4}{2} + \binom{4}{3}.  = 14$.

It seems like we have enough different squares to have one column free of monochromaticism. However, of those 14 squares, many will have monochromatic rows. For example, suppose we say that $\binom{n}{j}$ here means "choose $j$ out of $n=4$ vertices to be blue". Then, $\binom{4}{1}$ counts two squares with a top row that is red and two squares with a bottom row that is red. So, we can only use, at most, one of those, or else we'll create a red rectangle from two of our stacked squares. The same is true for $\binom{4}{3}$ but with blue rectangles. So, we're down to exactly eight squares. But now we can see that of the $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to make two vertices blue, at least some of them will do this by making two vertices on the same row blue and the other two red, and this violates the condition twice over.