# Question about alignment of objects

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Two CD’s, one is transparent and the other one is not, are partitioned into
200 equal sized circular sectors. On the first CD the sectors are coloured arbitrarily with
blue and yellow. To clarify, this means that we are given an arbitrary colouring, be it all blue, all yellow, or some irregular selection in between. This does not mean that we can arbitrarily colour the sectors.

On the second CD some 100 sectors are coloured blue and the other 100 yellow. I want to show that it is always possible to place the first CD on top of the second such that
the sectors align and at least 100 of the sectors look green.

I misinterpreted the question the first time around, and it is trivial to solve if we can arbitrarily colour the sectors of the first CD. I'm not sure how to solve the problem if the crux lies in the choice of alignment. I spent some time thinking about the problem but did not make any progress. Of course, in case the given colouring is a 'nice' one, then the proof for that case is obvious, but what about a general, irregular colouring? How does one proceed?

Comment: What was not so obvious to me initially is that a single tour is divided into 200 sectors (of angle 360°/200 each). So to formalise, you are _given_ two words of 200 letters each over the alphabet $\{B,Y\}$, where it is known that the second has equal numbers of $B$ and $Y$; it must be shown that there exists a cyclic permutation of (say) the first word such that its letters mismatch those of the second word in at least 100 places.

Answer (score 3):

You can align the two CDs in 200 different ways relative to one another.

Hint 1: What's the *average* number of green sectors?

Hint 2:

> To sum up the *total* number of green sectors for all the different alignments, rather than counting the number of green sectors for each alignment, take each sector on CD1, one by one, and count the number of alignments that makes it green.

Comment: @lucas Then consider my hint 2.

Comment: No. That's not what I mean (although it's an understandable misunderstanding, I've rephrased it now). Take a sector on CD1. How many alignments makes that sector green? Take the next sector. How many alignments makes that green? In total, how many green sectors are made as we try all 200 alignments?

Comment: Yes. So if each sector is green for exactly 100 different alignments, what is the total number of green sectors across all alignments?

Comment: @lucas I'm specifically not writing an answer because I don't want to give you an answer, I want to help you work through it yourself. Independence is irrelevant. Each sector is green 100 times, and there are 200 sectors. That makes it a total of $20\,000$ green sectors, regardless of how many are green or not green simultaneously. And if the total is $20\,000$, what's the average number of green sectors for an alignment?

Comment: @lucas And if the average is 100, could the maximum possibly be below 100?